# Date string format that sorted lexicographically ascending is chronologically descending?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, date, date-sorting

Encoding calendar dates as strings in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format (with or without separators, e.g. `2014-04-21`, `2014.04.21` or `20140421`) has the following properties:

- Sorting the strings lexicographically ascending (treating them as simple strings, unaware of what they represent) puts them in chronological order
- Converting between the calendar date and the string is obvious for humans (`2014-04-21` obviously represents `April 21, 2014`)

Note that for this to work, each component of the date (year, month and day) must always use the same number of characters, with leading zeroes if the number is too small. This means that `YYYY` can only represent years up to `9999`. If we want to represent 5-digit years too, then the date in my example above becomes `02014-04-21`.

## Question:

Is there a way to encode calendar dates as strings, such that sorting the strings lexicographically ascending puts them in reverse chronological order?

Ideally, it would be easy for a human to convert between the calendar date and the format you suggest, but even if you don't manage this (my solution below doesn't) I still want to know your solution.

If it helps, you may require this restriction:

- I only need to represent dates between Jan 1, 2001 and Dec 31, 2099.

## All I could come up with is this:

- Pick a Maximum Representable Year ahead of time, e.g. 2100
- Convert year-month-day to (2100-year), (13-month), (32-day) and add leading zeroes as explained above if any of these 3 numbers is too low.
- Thus `Apr 21, 2014` becomes `86-09-11`

The main problem with my solution is that it's not obvious to a human that `86-09-11` represents `April 21, 2014`.

## Notes:

- I know I can just sort the `YYYY-MM-DD` strings in descending order. That's not what I'm looking for.
- Your format doesn't have to represent the year, month and day separately in the string. For example you can encode a date as an integer showing “How many days are left before January 1, 2100” with zero padding to the left.
- Even if you can't find a format that's easy-to-read by a human, I still want to see your answer and know as many approaches to my question as possible.
- I'm not looking for a discussion of the month/day ambiguity. I imagine that some people may find `2001-01-02` ambiguous (either Jan 2 or Feb 1). But that doesn't matter here: the humans reading the format will know ahead of time what the format is (in this case `YYYY-MM-DD`) so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the format you started with and do a reverse sort (use a comparison function that tests for greater instead of less)...?

Comment: @twalberg sure we can do a reverse sort, but this was a more interesting problem to think about. Glad I asked, we already have a great answer from David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 9's complement -- write down the ISO date and then replace each digit by 9 minus that digit. At least I can apply in my head the encode/decode function (they're the same). I don't understand, however, why you don't just keep some redundant information around, turning 2006-01-02 into HJJD-JI-JH-2006-01-02, deriving 2006-01-02 -> 7993-98-97 -> HJJD-JI-JH by replacing 0 -> A, 1 -> B, 2 -> C, 3 -> D, 4 -> E, 5 -> F, 6 -> G, 7 -> H, 8 -> I, 9 -> J.

Comment: +1 for the idea of putting a human-readable date after the sortable encoding. The only drawback I see there is, although it's easy for a human to convert encoding -> calendar date, it's still hard to convert calendar date -> encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Long value of the date, if you have it.  Subtract that from Long.MAX_VALUE, right pad with 0s, and you've got a 19 digit number that will sort from newest to oldest when sorted in lexicographically ascending order.